# WP Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin: Error getting a chunk of thumbnail IDs to process.

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have installed and activated the Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin for my Wordpress site.

Whenever I try to regenerate the images there is an error that happens:

```
Regenerate Thumbnails: Error getting a chunk of thumbnail IDs to process. {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}abort: ƒ (a)arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 1name: "abort"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]always: ƒ ()complete: ƒ ()done: ƒ ()error: ƒ ()fail: ƒ ()getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)pipe: ƒ ()progress: ƒ ()promise: ƒ (a)readyState: 4responseText: "load_whoops[{"id":8},{"id":24},{"id":28},{"id":43},{"id":44},{"id":45},{"id":46},{"id":47},{"id":48},{"id":611},{"id":616},{"id":617},{"id":754},{"id":755},{"id":756},{"id":757},{"id":758},{"id":759},{"id":760},{"id":761},{"id":762},{"id":763},{"id":764},{"id":765},{"id":766}]"setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)state: ƒ ()status: 200statusCode: ƒ (a)statusText: "OK"success: ƒ ()then: ƒ ()__proto__: Object parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at a.parseJSON (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:9)
    at Xb (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at y (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
build.js?ver=3.0.2:1 Regenerate Thumbnails: Error getting a chunk of thumbnail IDs to process. {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at a.parseJSON (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:9)
    at Xb (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at y (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
build.js?ver=3.0.2:1 Regenerate Thumbnails: Error getting a chunk of thumbnail IDs to process. {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at a.parseJSON (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:9)
    at Xb (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at y (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.6:4)
```

How do I fix this?

I want to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have the old `WP REST API` plugin enabled. This plugin is no longer needed (and is actually outdated) now that the REST API is a part of WordPress itself.

Disable and delete that plugin and then things should work as expected.

Comment: Which particular plugin is that?  I only have 9 plugins installed: 1.) Akismet Anti-Spam 2.) Genesis Visual Hook Guide 3.) Hello Dolly 4.) podbean Shortcode 5.) Prevent Browser Caching 6.) Regenerate Thumbnails 7.) Starter Wordpress Plugin 8.) Wordpress Importer 9.) WP Subtitle

Comment: Its due to plugin conflict as i previously face this issue so please check by deactivating each plugin one by one may be this resolves the issue. I faced issued due to `WP REST API` plugin but you haven't used that plugin so may be other plugin is conflicting.

Comment: you are right.  It was 7.) Starter Wordpress Plugin that had the conflict.  The was a plugin I created following a tutorial...the plugin doesn't use REST API ....but o well...that was where the conflict is...

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late, but had the same issue.
Deleting the cookies did the trick for me.